# Error moving wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I`m trying to move my wordpress website from local computer to my new hosting. After compliting all guide steps I got an error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrEfe.png)

```
error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/casinost/websitename.online/www/wp-includes/home/casinost/websitename.online/www//load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/pear/php56') in /home/casinost/websitename.online/www/wp-settings.php on line 19
```

I understand that it might be some kind of path conflict of my old directory and new one, but how can I change this? Which file I need to modify to choose the correct directory?"

Comment: @NathanHughes Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/casinost/websitename.online/www/wp-includes/home/casinost/websitename.online/www//load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/pear/php56') in /home/casinost/websitename.online/www/wp-settings.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress always saves URLs as *absolute*  file paths, including `http://` or `https://`, the domain etc. This looks as if you have relatives filepaths in your `wp-settings.php file` which were not converted by whatever routine you used for the move to the other server. Compare those filepaths with all the other file paths/URLs which were converted correctly and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a wordpress site can be really hard, thats why there are some plugins for doing this with just a few clicks.

like: [Duplicator](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)

in the free version it should help you and do this task in a few minutes without headache.

Comment: you're welcome. Have a nice day and a lot of success for your website!